# number of sequences in a list

Tags: python, sequence

I need to determine the # of sequences that are in a list of integers. A member in the list can be part of the sequence is it falls in a range of 65. So in my list,

```
43
83
90
250
265
500
```

43,83,90 are all members in 1 sequence, they all fall in a range of 65. Also 250,265 make up 1 sequence. Right now my code creates tuples from the list. (43,83) (83,90) but It dosent know that they both are part of the same sequence.

```
while count < len(w_seq_list)-1:
 if((w_seq_list[count+1] > w_seq_list[count]) and ((w_seq_list[count+1] - w_seq_list[count]) <= 65)):

     wr.append((w_seq_list[count],w_seq_list[count+1])) // add tuple to sequence list
     count += 1
 else:
     count += 1
     continue
```

What can I add to determine if my tuples are in the same sequence to get a correct count? Let me know if you need any more clarification. Thanks!

Comment: What if you had `15, 43, 83, 90`? Would that be one sequence, or would you have two sequences: `15, 43` and `43, 83, 90`?

Comment: It would have to be 2. (90-15) > 65, and (83-15) > 65

Comment: but why would 43 be separated from 83 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def grouper(my_list):
    previous, temp, result = my_list[0], [my_list[0]], []
    for number in my_list[1:]:
        if number - previous > 65:
            result.append(temp)
            temp, previous = [number], number
        else:
            temp.append(number)
    if temp:
        result.append(temp)
    return result

assert(grouper([43, 83, 90, 250, 265, 500]) == [[43, 83, 90], [250, 265], [500]])
assert(grouper([15, 43, 83, 90]) == [[15, 43], [83, 90]])
```